# Python, Bioinformatics query

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am new to python and I would like to know if what I am attempting is possible. I have a section here from a DNA alignment and I was wondering if for each location of a gap "-" on the bottom I could identify the nucleotide on the top line. Here I would be looking to return "G".

My efforts so far have not been successful. The alignment is:

```
ATTCAGGCCTAGCA
:::::  :: ::::
ATTCAA-CCAAGCA
```

I appreciate any assistance!

Comment: In what form do you have the data? And please show what you have tried.

Comment: You're likely interested in the built-in function zip().

Comment: You will likely need two lists, or a list of lists.

Comment: Actually, a list comprehension would do, I'd bet.

Comment: If you want to learn more about python and bioinformatics, go to Rosalind.info -- they have a class for it and over 150 problems to solve (after you get better at it). Highly recommended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have any information about the data format, I will tell you the general process. Create 2 lists with the first and last line respectively (which I suppose are aligned and have the same length) and iterate over them. At each step verify if the character at the current position in the last array is a '-' and if so, print the character from the other array.

Comment: +1 I actually think this should be more the way to go when people are not showing any attempt. Someone downvoted it, I don't agree.

Comment: @Jblasco Yes, I agree. If I don't know the exact format, I will prefer not to give a code, since I don't have an idea what it is required. If the OP explains and gives me an exact input/output or code that doesn't work, I will gladly help him/her.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your data is saved. Let's say it's two equal length strings in a tuple:

```
dna_pair = ('ATTCAGGCCTAGCA','ATTCAA-CCAAGCA')
```

Then you could try:

```
def find_align(dna_pair):
    for i in range(len(dna_pair[0])):
        if dna_pair[1][i] == '-':
            return dna_pair[0][i]
```

Comment: this is what i was gonna say

Comment: if you do a for i,v in enumerate(dna_pair[1]): I think the code could be a little bit more clear, you'd need only to know if v == "-".

Comment: `for left_acid, right_acid in izip(*dna_pair): if right_acid == '-': return left_acid` is more pythonic. Not that I'm sure `return` is the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 1):

```
above = 'ATTCAGGCCTAGCA'
below = 'ATTCAA-CCAAGCA'
gap_letters = [above[i] for i,j in enumerate(below) if j=='-']
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use biopython library. It has many data types designed to manipulate DNA, RNA and protein sequences (alignments, trees, etc).
In this case AlignIO from biopython package will definitely help you.

```
from Bio import AlignIO
# reading your sequences:
alignment = AlignIO.read("my_seq.fa", "fasta")

# length of any alignment row is equal, so number of columns is here

cols = len(alignment[0])
# access to the rows and columns is like in the Numpy array
for col in range(cols):  
    if alignment[ : , col][1] == "-":
        print("gap!")
```